# mod_rewrite enabled, but .htaccess does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with my .htaccess.

on the phpinfo() page, I see that 'mod_rewrite' is in the 'loaded modules' under 'apache2handler', but my .htaccess does not work..

```
.htaccess 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

Do I have an error with .htaccess?

Comment: "Does not work" - Just like my car, can you help me on this? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

Options +FollowSymLinks

Above rewrite engine on and see if that works

Comment: I also encountered similar case, but I have "Options +FollowSymLinks" in the top line.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an error with .htaccess Apache will generally give you a 500 response.  To be honest, a "cheap" way that I use to make sure I have my configuration correct is to put garbage like "alksdjfalsdkjf" in .htaccess - error 500 means I enabled it, no error means I forgot something. ;)

You might want to check your AllowOverride settings.

Comment: AllowOverride was the culprit in my case